# How to intercept and forward keyboard strokes to computer

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to figure out the best way to intercept some keyboard commands without installing any software on a machine.

Im basically wanting to send a trigger (on / off) via bluetoothLE to a device when the space bay is pressed on the keyboard. Without installing software.

I'm thinking that i can intercept all key strokes by plugging the keyboard into the pi, and then forward them on to the computer via another cable? While then sending blue bluetoothLE via the pi.

Can anyone help me out with this, is it possible how I'm imagining it?

Comment: You want to plug a USB (?) keyboard into a Raspberry Pi and run a program you don't install to send the keystrokes on to some other unspecified computer via another unspecified cable while turning on a Bluetooth device whenever the space bar is pressed and turning it off at some other unspecified point. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah correct, no software of the target machine everything on the pi. And i don't want to turn on a bluetooth device, but just send a bluetoothLE / wifi signal to a tablet device (i think that is the easy part) to say that the space bar was pressed